# AJAX call not starting IIS worker process?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, jquery, iis-6, asmx

First of all, I'm not a pro on IIS configuration topic.

I got a website written in VB.NET 3.5 Web Forms.  I have a small web service, ASMX, running as a part of this website.  One page on the website calls the web service with AJAX (jQuery $.ajax function, post).  The server is running Windows 2003 and IIS 6.0.  The website and the web service are sharing the same Application Pool.

In IIS Application Pool properties there is a setting "Idle Timeout" which says "Shutdown worker processes after being idle for N (time in minutes)".  The problem is when the worker process shuts down after N minutes, it is not being started again on any of the AJAX calls from the page. What can I do in this kind of situation?  I've only dealt with .NET MVC before in terms of AJAX, and I have never seen anything like this.

There are no errors in the logs.  Here is what's being returned by the server through XmlHttpRequest:

> Ready State: 4
>
> Status: 500
>
> Status Text: Internal Server Error
>
> Xhr Message: undefined
>
> Response Text: {"Message":"There was
> an error processing the request.",
> "StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}

I was told that setting the Shutdown value to a big number, like 24 hours, would fix this. I guess it would, but to me it doesn't seem like a proper solution.

### Edit

This is the JavaScript $.ajax call.  I'm not sure if this will make any difference.

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyWebService.asmx/GetRecordsExceedingMessage",
    data: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
      LMM.Operative_CheckError(result);  //display Records Exceeding Message as validation error
    },
    error: function(xhr, status) {
      LMM.Operative_DisplayClientErrors(xhr);
    }
  });
```

EDIT:
I just remembered this little piece from Web.config of the website:

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <remove name="HttpGet"/>
    <remove name="HttpPost"/>
    <remove name="HttpPostLocalhost"/>
    <remove name="Documentation"/>
    <remove name="AnyHttpSoap"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Comment: If IIS is serving the page (therefore the worker process is obviously NOT idle), then immediately script is triggered via an AJAX call on that page, I don't see how this can happen.  Is it common for users to sit on a page for a long time before triggering whatever makes the AJAX call?

Comment: @Keith - Users seem to like having this page open and then stepping out to meeting/break/bathroom whatever.  When they're back, they get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the MyWebService.asmx/GetRecordsExceedingMessage actually a correct way of accessing your asmx? If you fetch that url manually, will it start the worker? It might also be that your handler only handles a certain content-type, hence your application/json won't trigger it.

I'm guessing that your handler-mapping isn't working, therefor IIS errors out and never starts your app-pool. Try activating detailed errors for IIS, I know you can do that for IIS7 and onwards, not sure how to do that in IIS6, maybe this will help:

> In IIS control panel select web site, right click to properties, then select the the custom errors tab.
>
> Now select all the custom pages (Click top page, press shift and click bottom page) and click set as default. All pages to now show as being default.
>
> Stop and the re-start IIS and now you should now get detailed errors.

Comment: @jishi - Thanks!  Let me mess with this.

Comment: I see know that your app seems to work as long as the worker is running, so I'm guessing the handler mappings are correct but wont wake the worker for some reason.

Comment: @jishi - You made me remember 1 more thing.  Please look at the post, I updated.

Comment: I never worked with .asmx services and I'm more familiar with IIS7, sorry. But it might be a good idea to post the relevant parts of your web.config aswell and hope that someone spots an obvious error. But HttpPost should probably be part of it?

Comment: @jishi - If I try hitting this URL manually after the worker process timed out, regardless of what's in Web.config I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".  Which makes no sense to me.

Comment: That means that it has nothing to do with the ajax-request. the OnStart event would fire when the worker has timed out and is restarted again, are you sure you don't have any code in there that would mess things up?

Comment: There was a piece of code that is checking for session being up.  It wouldn't break when the session times out, but it would break when the process is shut down.  I don't have a solution yet, but you got me going in the right direction.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See the following similar posting, which mentions how you can turn off the idle timeout altogether:  [Overcome compilation(?) pause on *secondary* initial ASP.Net application startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229613/overcome-compilation-pause-on-secondary-initial-asp-net-application-startup).  Or you can set the timeout like you said, or you can cheat and write a windows service on the server that makes requests to the site every few minutes.

Comment: If these are all the choices that I have, I'd rather go with disabling the time out. Would there be a downside to this? I would still think there has to be some other solution, some setting somewhere in IIS or maybe something I could do with those AJAX calls in JavaScript.

Comment: @Dimskiy - If the server has a heavy load, then keeping a worker process running indefinitely will waste resources obviously, but other than that I see no issue.  The app pool should still recycle every time it reaches a certain threshold (which you also have control over), but if the site is as idle as you mention, I doubt you'll ever hit it.

Comment: This is true for QA environment.  As for DEV, I'm currently the only one messing with things there.  However, I don't know what kind of load the PROD has :(

Comment: @Dimskiy - Well I would recommend reviewing Application logs on the production server to see if you can get a beat on how often the app pool is recycled/worker process is shut down.  If this isn't a concern on the production server, I wouldn't worry about it.  If it is, I would turn off the idle timeout and see if that improves the site.  You can always turn on IIS detailed debugging/logging, but I would have to look up how to do that in IIS6.